# Sudoers file changed, not able to enter choice about what to do, automatically enters N

Tags: sudo, kvm-virtualization

VERY new to Ubuntu here or command line OS at all, so I am not really at all sure what to do here, and googling hasn't helped in the least.

I just ran an update on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 machine and rebooted. I haven't ever touched the sudoers file, so I am suspecting some installed package did, then my update the other day tried to change that, but not sure, best guess. I am trying to create a virtual machine, and I get this error, but I have NO WAY to make a choice, it just uses default choice after about 5 milliseconds, doesn't wait for user input.

Is there some other way I can FORCE this modified sudoers thing to pop up again so that I can view the differences, or just replace it? The command I used that got this output is the following:

```
sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm trusty  --hostname TEST-vm
```

Here is the full output of the message in question. Also, not sure if the policy-rc.d thing is related, or what that does....

```
Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
Local time is now:      Sun Dec 18 17:59:54 UTC 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Sun Dec 18 17:59:54 UTC 2016.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.

Configuration file '/etc/sudoers'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** sudoers (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? dpkg: error processing package sudo (--configure):
 EOF on stdin at conffile prompt
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```